# Generate with nswag an openAPI document including swashbuckle custom operation filters

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, nswag

I'm using Swashbuckle in an ASP .NET MVC application which is configured with additional operation filters like so:

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c => {
                    c.OperationFilter<FooOpeartionFilter>();
                    c.OperationFilter<BarOpeartionFilter>();
                    //other confs
                    ...
```

In my .NET client application, I would like to automatically create API client code based on a .NET `MvcApplication.dll` which includes the Controller definitions.

For this I use NSWAG. I run firstly webapi2openapi to generate the openapi.json document

```
nswag webapi2openapi /assembly:MvcApplication.dll /output:MvcApplication.OpenApi.json
```

and then for creation of the client c# code:

```
nswag run configuration.nswag
```

with the `configuration.nswag` pointing to the `MvcApplication.OpenApi.json`

```
  "documentGenerator": {
    "fromDocument": {
      "url": "PATH\MvcApplication.OpenApi.json"
    }
  },
```

but the created openAPI document `MvcApplication.OpenApi.json` is lacking of changes to the API which the additional `OperationFilters` are providing. As I understand, this is expected as the Operation filters are added on asp .net application startup and we create the .json from a static .dll.

Is there a way to include the operation filters to the created `MvcApplication.OpenApi.json` based on a `MvcApplication.dll`? Is this possible? I have search for answer in the `nswag help` and navigated to `Command: webapi2openapi`, but non of the listed parameters seems to add those operation filters. Or maybe should I change my ASP .NET code and use NSWAG instead of swashbuckle?

Comment: You are mixing nswag in the cli and swashbuckle in the actual app - nswag will not pick up any swashbuckle filters. This will only work with ASP.NET Core and nswag in the app + nswag as cli...

Comment: Yes, that's the current state - nswag in client, Swashbuckle in the app. Work's well when generating the client code directly from running app, but I want to change it to generate the client code from the app static .dll, so the client code would not be depend on running app. Ok, so as I understand the only solution here is to move the app code from Swashbuckle to nswag and rewrite the swashbuckle OperationFilters to nswag OperationProcessors. Thanks, for the response.

Comment: Maybe swashbuckle also has a cli to gen the spec outside and then use that as input for the nswag client gen via cli